# Image is rotated correctly on mobile device, not on desktop

Tags: php, iphone, image, image-processing

I'm having a weird issue with my uploaded images. They're rotated correctly when I view them on iPhones and iPads, but whenever I try to view them on desktop, they're displayed with their wrong orientation.
I can't find the error, and after spending hours messing with the EXIF data I'm close to giving up.
After fixing the orientation, I'm also resizing the images, but that shouldn't interfere with the other code. In case it does, I'm including it.

I don't have enough reputation to upload images, but here's a link to them:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdayA.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgPrG.png

Here's the code I'm using to upload:

```
$path_parts = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$filepath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($filepath));

// Rotate image correctly!
$exif = exif_read_data($image);
if(!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
    switch($exif['Orientation']){
        case 1: // nothing
        break;
        case 2: // horizontal flip
        $image = imageflip($image, IMG_FLIP_HORIZONTAL);
        break;
        case 3: // 180 rotate left
        $image = imagerotate($image,180,0);
        break;
        case 4: // vertical flip
        $image = imageflip($image, IMG_FLIP_VERTICAL);
        break;
        case 5: // vertical flip + 90 rotate right
        $image = imageflip($image, IMG_FLIP_VERTICAL);
        $image = imagerotate($image,-90,0);
        break;
        case 6: // 90 rotate right
        $image = imagerotate($image,-90,0);
        break;
        case 7: // horizontal flip + 90 rotate right
        $image = imageflip($image, IMG_FLIP_HORIZONTAL);
        $image = imagerotate($image,-90,0);
        break;
        case 8:    // 90 rotate left
        $image = imagerotate($image,90,0);
        break;
    }
}

switch ($path_parts['extension']) {
    case 'gif' :
    $im = imagecreatefromgif($image);
    break;
    case 'jpg' :
    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
    break;
    case 'png' :
    $im = imagecreatefrompng($image);
    break;
    case 'bmp' :
    $im = imagecreatefrombmp($image);
    break;
}
if($im){
    imagejpeg($im, $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 40);    
}
$image_path = 'd_'.time() . "." . $path_parts['extension']; 
$move_result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], '../img/results/' . $image_path);
```

If you have any idea why it's only rotating correctly on some platforms, I'd be very grateful!

EDIT: Should probably clarify that images will most often be uploaded from smartphones or tablets.

Comment: Probably not directly related to your stated problem but `imageflip()` returns `bool`, not a resource, so you shouldn't assign it to `$image` and then try to `imagerotate()`.

Comment: Oh. Right. Thanks, Tim!
Which method am I supposed to use to flip images?

Comment: Just use `imageflip()` without assigning the return value.  It manipulates the resource directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some errors that stop the code working.  Try turning on [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.errors.basics.php) to help you debug problems like this.

- `exif_read_data()` works on a file, not a GD resource, so pass `$filepath` instead of `$image`.
- `imageflip()` manipulates the resource directly and returns a `bool` so assigning the return value to `$image` destroys the resource.
- The second `switch()` statement isn't needed at all.  The `imagecreatefrom___()` functions create a resource from a file, but you're passing them an already created resource - all you want to do is output it.

Otherwise the orientation correction seems accurate and should work for you (it does on the various test photos I took with my phone).

Here's the corrected code:

```
$path_parts = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$filepath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($filepath));

// Rotate image correctly!
$exif = exif_read_data($filepath);
if (!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
    switch ($exif['Orientation']) {
        case 1: // nothing
            break;
        case 2: // horizontal flip
            imageflip($image, IMG_FLIP_HORIZONTAL);
            break;
        case 3: // 180 rotate left
            $image = imagerotate($image, 180, 0);
            break;
        case 4: // vertical flip
            imageflip($image, IMG_FLIP_VERTICAL);
            break;
        case 5: // vertical flip + 90 rotate right
            imageflip($image, IMG_FLIP_VERTICAL);
            $image = imagerotate($image, -90, 0);
            break;
        case 6: // 90 rotate right
            $image = imagerotate($image, -90, 0);
            break;
        case 7: // horizontal flip + 90 rotate right
            imageflip($image, IMG_FLIP_HORIZONTAL);
            $image = imagerotate($image, -90, 0);
            break;
        case 8:    // 90 rotate left
            $image = imagerotate($image, 90, 0);
            break;
    }
}

imagejpeg($image, $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 40);

$image_path = 'd_'.time() . "." . $path_parts['extension'];
$move_result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], '../img/results/' . $image_path);
```